# Python Pandas unable to query string variable

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'm trying to merge two datatables using address as the unique key. For one datatable, I'm not able to even query a string value while the other datatable I can. The test address I'm specifying is '2840 28TH AVE S'

Here is the test:
[Missing Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOmh7.png)

Here is the base table with address:
[Base table with address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGrJK.png)

Here is the different table where I did an address query, and it worked
[Functional syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06vIO.png)

I looked at the datatypes for the original table, nothing is glaring, and also checked for white spaces. How can I fix this? The syntax seems to be alright
[Datatypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvqSM.png)

Comment: Remember that capitalization must match as well.

Comment: Perhaps you should try `Hen.query("'2840' in address")` to see if you can find the record at all.

Comment: No record still comes up. I'm going to pull the original csv file as  all datatype strings to see if that fix things up

Comment: I figured it out it was something with white spaces. Here is how I tested it

Checked if actually string:
Hen['add1']=Hen['address'].str[:15]

Then this query worked. I guess trailing empty spaces may be causing it
Hen.query("add1=='2840 28TH AVE S'")

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a proper striping of the white space to make it work!

Hen['Street']= Hen['address'].str.strip()